# Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject wouldn't provide object

Tags: vb.net, image, resources

I cannot figure out, or google an answer, why pulling an image from project resources this way doesn't work:

```
    Dim MIIcon As Image
    Dim obj As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Item22")  'file: "Item22.png"
    MIIcon = DirectCast(obj, Image) 
    Me.PictureBox2.Image = MIIcon
```

The obj is nothing. Neither it works with file extension included. While this (direct path) works (but it wouldn't when deployed, of course):

```
    Dim MIIcon2 As Image
    MIIcon2 = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\****\documents\visual studio \Projects\******\Resources\Item22.png")
    Me.PictureBox3.Image = MIIcon2
```

Did I missed something? I must have done that couple of times in past.
This test code is run at Form1_Load() event. Obviously, I can see the Item22.png in my resources in VS.

**EDIT**

I added the sample image using Visual Studio: Project Resources context menu -> Add... -> Existing item

Comment: Did you remember to embed the icon in the resx file?

Comment: Does it work if you try to get a simple string?

Comment: obj is Nothing, so I guess it won't get a string. Do I have to add it to Resources.resx, when I added the PNG image using VS (Resources context menu -> Add... -> Existing item)? I'd assumed it had to be added along. I don't see it within the file, neither I can access it via My.Resources.Item22, but that behaviour I consider normal (though strange). Sometimes an inserted image appears there right away, sometimes after VS restart and sometimes never. I suppose this is by design, but I never found an explanation.

Comment: Yes, it must be added to your project's .resx. That's the only way to make it accessible through `My.Resources`. The `Resources` folder is just a folder. You can put anything in it, but that doesn't mean that it's included in the resources. The folder only exists so that VS has a way of referencing them at design time.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I have always thought what's in Resources is a resource, but I see this was totally wrong. I think I know why some appear there - that's because most of the time I add them via Button.Image property -> Select Resource - Project resource file: Import. This way it gets added. Is there any other way (apart code)? Please post it as answer, I marke it (after testing).

Comment: There is another, I wrote an answer about it as you wrote your comment. Though it is not possible to add resources via code. They're static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make an image accessible through `My.Resources` is to add it to your project's `.resx` file. The `Resources` folder exists only so that VS has a way of referencing the resources at design time. Adding files to it will **not** include them in the actual resources.

To add a new resource:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Properties` **(fig. 1)**.
2. Go to the `Resources` tab **(fig. 2)**.
3. Drag and drop your resources into VS **(fig. 3)**.

> **Fig. 1:**
>
> [image: Project Properties]

---

> **Fig. 2:**
>
> [image: Resources]

---

> **Fig. 3:**
>
> [image: Drag and drop resources]

Comment: @Oak_3260548 : Glad I could help! Good luck!