# Visual Studio can no longer import images

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to import an image and the import button (In the select resource window, local and project resource both don't work) doesn't  seem to work even in any type of control. I've tried reinstalling vb but it the issue remains.

[image: can not import image vb.net]

Comment: can u tell us what caused it? i mean if it was working before,then which of actions/after which action of yours this problem started?

Comment: it was a long time ago the last time I touched this project so I really can't tell. Problem still persists even with a new project so I guess it's probably an error to vb itself and not the project I'm working on.

Comment: there might be bug....any recent updates u did?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. My windows update us turned off. I tried reinstalling it but nothing changed. Maybe I should reinstall something else like the .NET framework or something?

Comment: Seems like a VS bug. As a temporary workaround you should be able to add them through the project's resources page. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47513918/3740093

Comment: it worked now! I also tried adding an existing item to this resource tab but it doesnt work too. Anyways thanks for this! Really big help..